# Slingshot no longer responds to Super+Space

Tags: elementary-os, pantheon, slingshot-launcher

I'm on elementary Luna (Ubuntu 12.04) and the built-in Slingshot Launcher no longer responds to the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> keyboard shortcut to launch the applications menu. Clicking the "Applications" button displays the panel, but I can't get it to display using the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to resetting the shortcut in tweaks?